# How to quickly navigate function arg lists in vim

Tags: vim

I have the following function definition:

```
def test(these, are=0, args=1):
    pass
```

I want to find a quick and intuitive way to hop between each argument.

For example, pressing `w`/`b` is too slow because it will hit the commas, but even worse it is it will hit the `=`. `W`/`B` works great except with that first argument because `test(these` is a "WORD".

Is there an existing way to navigate this list that works the same for all arguments, or is there a common modification to do this? For example, can I redefine what a WORD is and make the `(`/`)` break up a WORD? I can't think of a good example of when I would have a legitimate WORD with a paren right in the middle.

Comment: You could define a map like `nnoremap <m-a>  f,w` to move to the next argument, and a similar map to move to the previous argument.

Comment: It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but take a look at https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion

Comment: I just use `f,` then `;` or `,` to move between them or `f=`. `2f,` takes me to the third argument, etc. `/,/e+2` or `/=/e+1` and `n` or `N` also work. I'm just happy I don't have to flick switches to edit or repunch cards.

Answer (score 1):

The big complication with argument lists is complex expressions and nested function calls (e.g. `foo(1, bar(2, 3), 4)`). To handle those, at least some basic parsing is necessary; simple pattern matching (as can be done with built-in commands) won't do.

I personally use a combination of basic Vim commands, tailored to the current situation (i.e. `w` / `W` / `f{char}`), and the following plugins:

- [sideways](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/sideways.vim) has mappings to jump to next / previous arguments, to move arguments around, and corresponding text objects
- [fieldtrip](https://github.com/tek/vim-fieldtrip) builds on top of sideways and offers a *submode*, where individual keypresses can then be used to jump / move

Answer (score 0):

Just try using `ft` `f0` or `f1` to see if these jumps can help you.